Problem while implementing a function in a conditional bash command using background operator (&)
I'm working on a Bash script where I need to show a spinner animation function while checking if a specified Git remote exists. The script snippet for checking the Git remote is as follows:
read remote_to_pull_from
if ! git remote show $remote_to_pull_from &>/dev/null; then
    echo "Remote '$remote_to_pull_from' does not exist, exiting..."
    return 1
fi

This snippet works correctly and checks if the remote exists. Now, I want to add a spinner function to show an animation while the git remote show command is running. The spinner function, credited to this post, is as follows:
spinner() {
    local PROC="$1"
    local str="${2:-'Running...'}"
    local delay="0.1"
    tput civis  # hide cursor
    printf "\033[1;34m"
    while [ -d /proc/$PROC ]; do
        printf '\033[s\033[u[ / ] %s\033[u' "$str"; sleep "$delay"
        printf '\033[s\033[u[ — ] %s\033[u' "$str"; sleep "$delay"
        printf '\033[s\033[u[ \ ] %s\033[u' "$str"; sleep "$delay"
        printf '\033[s\033[u[ | ] %s\033[u' "$str"; sleep "$delay"
    done
    tput cnorm  # restore cursor
    return 0
}

I attempted to integrate the spinner with my conditional check using the approach mentioned in the Stack Overflow post, where the spinner animation is run in the background using a background operator (&). Here is the code I used to get it running while my condition is being checked:
read remote_to_pull_from
if ! git remote show $remote_to_pull_from &>/dev/null & spinner $!; then
    echo "Remote '$remote_to_pull_from' does not exist, exiting..."
    return 1
fi

The spinner spins, but the condition fails, and the script echoes the error message, while without the spinner, the condition works correctly.
I'm expecting the spinner function to run while the git remote show command is executing, and if the remote doesn't exist, the script should echo the error message and exit. How can I correctly use this spinner function with my conditional check, I think I'm missing a logical step here and breaking the condition when mixing it with that function? How can I handle this? Additionally, can you explain the usage of $! in this context?
Thank you everyone.

The basic problem here is that the if is testing the exit status of the spinner function, not the git command. As for $!, that gets the process ID of the most backgrounded git command.

@GordonDavisson Is it the default behavior of if to test the exit status of the second argument after &? how can I modify it to only test the first part of it, meaning the git command?

if always tests the exit status of the command between if and then. If it's a compound command (like multiple commands joined with &, ;, &&, ||, etc), that follows the usual rules for the exit status of a compound command, namely that the last command within the compound command's exit status is used. Backgrounded commands add another complication, since they don't return an exit status until sometime later; you need to use something like the wait command to want for them to finish and get their exit status.

Not a complete rewrite but you're looking for something like this:
spinner() {
    while kill -0 $! >/dev/null 2>&1; do
        for pipe in '/' '-' '\' '|'; do
            printf '%s Running...\r' "$pipe"
            sleep .1
        done
    done
    printf '\n'
    wait $!
}

read -p 'Enter remote name: ' remote
if git remote show "$remote" >/dev/null 2>&1 & ! spinner; then
    printf 'Remote %q does not exist.\n' "$remote" >&2
    exit 1
fi


Would you please explain the changes you made and why they work?

@Ilgar It's all written in the manual. The main difference is this version of spinner returns the exit status of git instead of 0, and the exclamation mark negates the exit status of spinner, not the command preceding it.

I'm still unable to figure out why this works, would you kindly explain the changes you made?
